# GridView onRowUpdating Event access to textBox

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I got i strange situations.
This is a part of the ascx code of my gridview

```
<asp:gridview ID="grdBooks" class="grdBooks" runat="server" width="100%" DataKeyNames="RecId,RefAuthorsRecId,RefBooksTypeRecId" autogeneratecolumns="false" onDataBound="grdBooks_dataBound" onPreRender="grdBooks_preRender" onrowediting="grdBooks_RowEdit" onrowupdating="grbBooks_onRowUpdating" onrowupdated="grdBooks_onUpdated" autogenerateeditbutton="true" onrowcancelingedit="grdBooks_onCancelingEdit">
            <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Title">
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtgrdTitle" runat="server" width="200px"></asp:TextBox>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblgrdTitle2" runat="server" visible="false" Text='<%# Eval("Title") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblgrdTitle" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Title") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>.....
```

This is a part of the "onRowEdit" and "onRowUpdating"

```
protected void grdBooks_RowEdit(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
{
    grdBooks.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
    grdBooks.DataSource = book;
    grdBooks.DataBind();
    TextBox txtTitle = grdBooks.Rows[e.NewEditIndex].FindControl("txtgrdTitle") as TextBox;
    Label lblTitle = grdBooks.Rows[e.NewEditIndex].FindControl("lblgrdTitle") as Label;
    txtTitle.Text = lblTitle.Text;
}
protected void grbBooks_onRowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e) 
{
    TextBox txtTitle = grdBooks.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtgrdTitle") as TextBox;
    ....
}
```

The problem is:

- the rowEdit works fine, change all the row of the grid in editable textboxes. The problem is that i write something in the text boxes and when i press "update" and go into the "onRowUpdate" method i haven't the new text(that i have inserted) in the textbox object that i have initialize. I got the old one.

(as u see now i use a not visible label in the editTemplate that carry the value of the original Title. Before i had Eval("title") on the textbox text but i thought that this was the probl so i try this other way)

Comment: Use the  `e.NewValues` dictionary

Answer (score 0):

As your datasource is book.Get the currentrow of the datatable and update values in that row.Then bind the grid again.

```
 GridViewRow gridEditRow = this.grdBooks.Rows[e.RowIndex];
 DataRow CurentRow = book.Rows[gridEditRow.DataItemIndex];

CurentRow["Title"] = (gridEditRow.FindControl("txtgrdTitle") as TextBox).Text;
```

Comment: The problem is not populate the dt. Is that i can't retrive the text i wrote into the textbox. The value of the .Text is always "" (empty). This is my example and also with your code, so with the findControl in the exact row